# Multiple Ternary Operators

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I need a bit of syntax help with a ternary operator which will help me to put the correct marker icons on to my good map. I have three areas 0, 1 and 2 which have unique icons 0, 1 and 2.

I used to have just two areas so this ternary operator worked fine;

```js
var icon = (area == 1) ? icon1 : icon0;
```

Now I need to add an additional third icon (icon2) for area2.

I've tried various methods but just can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```js
var icon = (area == 1) ? icon1 : (area == 2) ? icon2 : icon0;
```

But this is starting to get complicated. You may well be better off just creating a function to do this work instead:

```js
var icon = getIcon(area);

function getIcon(area) {
  if (area == 1) { 
    return icon1; 
  } else if (area == 2) { 
    return icon2; 
  }

  return icon0;
}
```

Comment: After I wrote this, I realized that 0 always maps to icon0, so Pointy's answer is preferable. However, this approach is still viable if you need a 'catch-all' value such as `icon0` in this case.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I decided the function best suited my needs. I also find it more friendly to work with rather than ternary operator which may grow even bigger over time. Thanks.

Answer (score 49):

For anyone that's confused about the multiple ternary syntax (like I was), it goes like this:

```
var yourVar = condition1 ? someValue
            : condition2 ? anotherValue
            : defaultValue;
```

You can add as many conditions as you like.

You can read up further on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 30):

How about:

```js
var icon = [ icon0, icon1, icon2 ][area];
```

Comment: Yes that's a good point - it relies on "area" being well-behaved, so to speak.

Comment: I like this method but marked Justin's as the answer as it best suited by needs. Many thanks for this tip.

Comment: What is this operation called?

Comment: @JM-AGMS it's just a simple array index operation. The `area` variable contains a number.

Comment: `['A', 'B', 'C'][area]` so if area = 2, `C` would be the value? I never even thought to define and set the array index at the same time.

Comment: @JM-AGMS yes, that's right. An array literal is just as much an array as a variable whose value is an array.

Comment: If you wanted icon0 to be a fallback, it would just be `icon: { 1: icon1, 2: icon2 }[area] || icon0`

Answer (score 14):

How about an object literal.

```
icons = {
    0: icon0,
    1: icon1,
    2: icon2
}

icon = icons[area];
```

Answer (score 8):

**Very simple way**

If your object is like this:

```js
var obj = {
  x: true,
  y: {
    xy: 'some value'
  }
}

var result = obj ? obj.y ? obj.y.xy ? obj.y.xy : 'N/A' : 'N/A' : 'N/A'

console.log(result) // "some value"
```

Comment: this is not a very good test, as `test1 ? test1 : (test2 ? test2 : 'some default value')` and `(test1 ? test1 : test2) ? test2 : 'some default value'` both give the same result

Comment: a better test would be: `var test = true; var result = test===true ? 'it is true' : test===false ? 'it is false' : 'it is null'`. That way when you group the last two operators, `test===true ? 'it is true' : (test===false ? 'it is false' : 'it is null')`, you get `'it is true'` (correct), but when you group the first two operators, `(test===true ? 'it is true' : test===false) ? 'it is false' : 'it is null'`, you get `'it is false'` (incorrect). This test is better because it shows you the implicit operator groupings.

Answer (score 7):

```js
var icon = (area == 0) ? icon0 : (area == 1) ? icon1 : icon2;
```

Comment: quick Q: are the brackets necessary?

Comment: @BugWhisperer I believe you mean the parenthesis, and no the parenthesis are not necessary was just trying to show separation.

Comment: yes thats what i meant. ok, i know in some contexts the brackets are necessary which is why i asked

Answer (score 0):

A sequence of question mark operators `?` can return a value that depends on more than one condition.

For instance:

```
let age = prompt('age?', 18);

let message = (age < 3) ? 'Hi, baby!' :
  (age < 18) ? 'Hello!' :
  (age < 100) ? 'Greetings!' :
  'What an unusual age!';

alert( message );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
condition1 ? (condition2 && condition2*Passed*) || condition2*NotPassed* : condition1NotPassed
```

Now if your first condition is passed then the second phase will be taken into account if not, else section (in our ternary the code after `:` will run; now we consider that the first condition is passed so we are in 2nd phase and this code checks that if in this phase condition 2 is in charge **and** if it is passed then the output of parentheses section will be **true** else the parentheses output will be charged with **or** operator in this case the second operand will be taken as else part of if statement