# multiple condition in ternary operator in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
<div style={{'backgroundColor': status === 'approved' ? 'blue' : 'black'}}>
</div>
```

black is the default color but what if I want to add the 3rd condition?

status can be 'approved', 'rejected', 'pending' or more.

Comment: Really, you should only use a ternary if you have 2 possible results. You can "chain" ternaries to add more possible results, but it tends to get messy fast. Just use an `if`.

Comment: Don't handle it all in the JSX. I'd write a function that returns the right color based on the status, and call the function from the JSX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Ternary Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757549/multiple-ternary-operators)

Comment: Would be nice to have an inline "switch" like if/elseif/else option in React/JSX.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
<div style={{'backgroundColor': status === 'approved' ? 'blue' : status === 'pending' ? 'black' : 'red'}}>
</div>
```

This means if `status === 'approved'` set the background color as blue, if `status === 'pending'` set it as black, else set it as red.

Comment: I feel like this compromises readability way too much. It takes longer to understand what the code is doing. A code that's easier to read is easier to enhance and maintain. Code quality tools such as SonarQube and even some linters would throw a warning in here because of the nested ternary operators.

Answer (score 38):

I would suggest using functions if your conditions get complicated, to not degrade your code readability.

```
getBackgroundColor(status) {
    if (status === 'approved') {
        return 'blue';
    }
    if (status === 'pending') {
        return 'red';
    }
    return 'black';
}

render() {
    // ...

    return (
        <div style={{ 'backgroundColor': this.getBackgroundColor(status) }}></div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Chaining ternary statements like some other answers are suggesting is absolutely unreadable and a terrible practice. This solution is clear and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is a very nice practice, thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

To chain ternary operations you need to add another ternary operator to be returned when the conditions are not met, for example:

`a === true ? a : b`

In place of `b` you would add a new ternary operator, like so:

`a === true ? a : b === true ? b : c`

Bonus:

When you're just checking for null/undefined/false you can use the pipe operator, for example this:

`var x = a !== null ? a : b;`

Can be simplified to:

`var x = a || b;`

And pipe operators can be chained infinitely like ternary operators.

Comment: on second condition how that ternary operator works?

Answer (score 2):

There is another way how to do it with the a bit more readable & cleaner code style. We can replace the ternary operator with the object literal and use this instead of nesting ternary operators, like so

```
function getBackgroundColor(status){
  const backgroundColorByStatus = {
    approved: 'blue',
    pending: 'black',
    default: 'red',
  }

  return backgroundColorByStatus[status] || backgroundColorByStatus['default']
}

// somewhere below
<div style={{'backgroundColor': getBackgroundColor(status)}}>fancy div</div>
```

With this approach you can have multiple colors and code will be still clean & readable :)

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple condition in ternary operator in `JSX` and `JS`

```
style={{'backgroundColor': status === 'approved' ? 'blue' : status === 'cancel' ? 'red' : 'green'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple ternary operators is not a good idea, better to use a function and put if-else conditions inside that and call that function from render. It helps you to make the render part clean and short.

Like this:

```
<div style={{'backgroundColor': this._style(status)}}></div>

_style(status){
    if(status == 'approved')
        return 'blue';
    else if(status == 'pending')
        return 'black';
    else return 'red';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd handle it separately as other types of status may appear in the future.

```
const getBackgroundColor(status) {
  if (status === 'approved') {
    return 'blue'
  }
  else if (status === 'pending') {
    return 'black'
  } else {
    return 'red'
  }
}

<div style={{'backgroundColor': getBackgroundColor(status) }}>
</div>
```

Code gets easier to understand and reason about.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use ternary because it gets hard to read.   Why not store the status and associated colors in an object then just reference that?

```
const colors = {approved:"blue", rejected:"red"};


<div style={{'backgroundColor':status in colors ? colors[status] : "black"}}>
</div>
```

Oops, I didn't realize how old this thread was.

Answer (score -1):

Inside render you can create an empty array variable. As shown below, you can apply nested styling. Also, you won't need a nested ternary operator.

```
let styleValue = [];
if(status === 'approved') {
  styleValue.push({backgroundColor:'blue'})
} else {
  styleValue.push({backgroundColor:'black'})
}

<div style={styleValue}>
</div>
```