# how can i use 3 conditions or more in js jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, api, google-maps

my code is like  :

```
Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon: locations[i][5] === 'Red' ? red_icon : locations[i][5] === 'Purple' ? 
                purple_icon : blue_icon

            });
```

i set condition for the icon if red then it will be use the red icon if purple then purple icon else it will be use blue for all otherwise....
** my problem when i add another condition the code didn't work anymore...
like :

```
icon: locations[i][5] === 'Red' ? red_icon : locations[i][5] === 'Purple' ? 
                purple_icon : locations[i][5] === 'blue' ? blue_icon : green_icon
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757549/multiple-ternary-operators) answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch-case to the rescue:

```
let whatIconToUse = green_icon;

switch(locations[i][5]) {
    case 'Red':
        whatIconToUse = red_icon;
        break;
    case 'Purple':
        whatIconToUse = purple_icon;
        break;
    case 'blue':
        whatIconToUse = blue_icon;
        break;
    default:
        whatIconToUse = green_icon;
        break;
}

Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: whatIconToUse 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use a switch statement

```js
    let icon = '';
    switch(locations[i][5]) {
      case "Red":
        icon = red_icon
        break;
      case "Purple":
        icon = purple_icon
        break;
      case "blue":
        icon = blue_icon
        break;
    }

    Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: icon
    });
```

or you can use a (dirty) trick

```js
    Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: eval(locations[i][5].toLowerCase() + '_icon')
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use an associative array for this:

```
var iconMap = {
 'Red': red_icon,
 'Blue': blue_icon,
 // etc
}
```

Then your code becomes *much* simpler to read:

```
var icon = locations[i][5];
Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon:  iconMap[icon]
        });
```

Comment: No need for an associative array. Red becomes red, Purple becomes purple, Green becomes green... See a pattern here? No need to list all possible colors one by one.

Comment: @JeremyThille you've misunderstood the detail as I posted under your answer. Its a _variable_ `red_icon` not the string "red_icon". I'm associating the string "Red" with the variable `red_icon`

Comment: Ah, right, but what does these variables contain? Why are they not just strings? The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers) says they should be just strings, paths to image file (icon.png)

Comment: @JeremyThille because quite often you have meaningful variable names `red_icon` pointing to a resource such as "Some_icon_file.ico"

Comment: Sounds overkill to me. We could just have `\`path/to/icons_folder/${color}_icon.png\``

Comment: ...and that is indeed what _I_ would do! But it doesn't answer *this* question!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parenthesis in order to nest ternary operators (those of form `boolean ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

In your particular case,

```
icon: locations[i][5] === 'Red' ? red_icon : (locations[i][5] === 'Purple' ? 
                purple_icon : (locations[i][5] === 'blue' ? blue_icon : green_icon))
```

However, a `switch` statement would make things much more readable and easily extendable:

```
let color;
switch(locations[i][5]) {
    "Red": { color = red_icon; break; }
    "Purple": { color = purple_icon; break; }
    // add all cases here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

And why not simply :

```
icon: locations[i][5].toLowerCase() + "_icon"
```

"Red" -> "red_icon"

"Purple" -> "purple_icon"

Comment: I'd assume that the _variable_ `red_icon` may well hold something along the lines of "xyz123abc.jpg".

Comment: I don't get it?