# Is there a way to do "if/else if/else" statements ( aka check multiple conditions ) inline in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, jsx

So I know that if I only have one condition to check I can put `{ condition ? results : elseresults }` in JSX instead of the

```
if (condition) {
  results
} else {
  elseresults
}
```

in normal Javascript. But is there a way to check multiple conditions, where I would do

```
if (condition) {
} else if (condition 2) {
} else {
}
```

in normal JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ condition1 ? result1 : condition2 ? result2 : resultElse }`

Same as regular js: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55958241/12270342

Comment: Perhaps you should flag as duplicate if all you really do is link to another answered post on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<>
    {condition && (jsx)}
    {condition2 && (jsx)}
</>
```

Other thing you can do is:

```
let jsx;
if (condition) {
    jsx = x
} else if (condition 2) {
    jsx = y
} else {
    jsx = z
}

<>{jsx}</>
```

Or you can do nested ternaries!