# javascript if..else statement to ? :

Tags: javascript

newbie here. Thanks for your helps.

I'm wondering can I change if ...else ... to ? : statement in following codes:

https://codepen.io/lgtits/pen/MWoqPBX?editors=1010

```
list.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  let target = event.target
  if (target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    let parentElement = target.parentElement
    parentElement.remove()
  } else if (target.tagName === 'LABEL') { 
    target.classList.toggle('checked')
  }
})
```

just like this:

```
let a = 1

let b = 2

if(a>b) {
  console.log('bigger')
} else if (a === b) {
  console.log('equal')
} else {
  console.log('smaller')
}

a > b ? console.log('bigger') : 
      a === b ? console.log('equal') :
      console.log('smaller')
```

Comment: There's no `else` there, so `?:` doesn't make much sense. That code also doesn't produce a value like `?:` does, so it's inappropriate.

Comment: There is no else in your first example, but you could do `target.classList.contains('delete') && target.parentElement.remove()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Ternary Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757549/multiple-ternary-operators)

Comment: Check out [Ternary Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: sorry my mistake QQ

Comment: there are multiple line in the codes example 1, but in the sample below , it's much more easier.

Comment: Before asking if you _could_, you should consider if you _should_... Shorter isn't necessarily better. Ternary statements can make short assignments more compact, but for  longer blocks like that, just use `if`/`else`.

Comment: The answer is **no**. Ternary statements are used to return a _value_. Since you're not producing a value, but executing a function, this is not appropriate to use in this case.

Comment: yes I know it won't be more readable, but I try many times but it didn't work...so I came here to ask for some solution.

Comment: @Nsevens Well, you *can*: `<cond> ? <func call> : null`. It just doesn't make much sense.

Comment: here my codepen: https://codepen.io/lgtits/pen/MWoqPBX?editors=1010

Comment: Javascript needs something like in kotlin, that is const foo = if () ... else .... Javascript doesn't have that but easily reproducible with a ternary: const foo = ... ? ... : ... . Better than let foo; if ()... foo = ... else foo = ... Other than that, I agree with the others, the ternary expression wasn't meant to replace if else completely. Also, you should avoid nesting ternary expressions whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the first block `if...else if` to the following:

```js
list.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  let target = event.target;
  // set this ahead of time if needed
  let parentElement = target.parentElement;
  target.classList.contains("delete")
    ? parentElement.remove()
    : target.tagName === "LABEL"
      ? target.classList.toggle("checked")
      : void 0;
});
```

It can tend to get clunky if you have too many different things to check for, but it's doable if you're only doing one operation each in `if` and `else` blocks. Just remember to make sure it is readable.

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work in my project. it can't delete the item..

Comment: https://codepen.io/lgtits/pen/MWoqPBX?editors=1010

Comment: My mistake. I forgot the `.remove()` in my code. It should work with that in there.

Comment: can I put these in one line ? let parentElement = target.parentElement &  parentElement.remove()

Comment: If you're deleting the element shortly after, don't bother assigning it to a variable. I think that `parentElement` would be undefined after that line executes and would not be helpful to you anyway.

Comment: Be sure to read [Conditional Chains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#conditional_chains) for further reading.

Comment: Actually, attempting to reference a variable before it has been set will throw a `ReferenceError` (for `parentElement.remove()` before it has been assigned). Also, make sure you use the logical AND (`&&`) as the single ampersand is considered the bitwise AND (`&`) and may not yield the results you think it will. Using `target.parentElement && target.parentElement.remove();` will work fine if you just want to remove the parentElement.